# clearinterval not working on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Clear Interval not working in slider i have tried a lot but facing same issue is there any one can tell what is problem here and how i can get this resolved? This is a Image slider in Jquery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var current = 2;
    var sl = $(".aa").length;
    var interval;
    function startSlider() {
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        $(".slider-wrapper").delay(2000);
        $(".slider-wrapper").animate({
          'margin-left': '-=910'
        }, 2000, function() {
          current++;
          if (current === sl) {
            current = 1;
            $(".slider-wrapper").delay(2000).animate({
              'margin-left': '0'
            }, 2000);
          }
        })
      }, 3000);
    }
    function stopSlider() {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    $(".slider-wrapper").on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);
    startSlider();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Try to log ``interval`` to the screen using ``console.log(interval)`` to see if it is there(from your browser developer tool console tab ctrl+shift+i).

Comment: i have checked this already there is no error

Comment: Does it return any integer value ?

Comment: Can u send post the html code for it.

Comment: <body>

<nav>
 <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">hello</a></li>
     </ul>
   
   
   </li>

 
 </ul>


</nav>

<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
   <img src="images/1.jpg"  class="aa"/>
 <img src="images/2.jpg" class="aa" />
 <img src="images/3.jpg"  class="aa" />
  </div>


</div>
</div>

</div>

</body>

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that because `interval` variable is a global variable(associated with the window and can be accessed using `window.interval` or `interval` if we are in the context of the window)

Whereas when you are calling `stopSlider` inside `$(".slider-wrapper").on('mouseenter'`, `this` keyword is reffering to `$(".slider-wrapper")` element and not `window`.

In other words `interval` is not defined in this context.

To solve this problem just execute `stopSlider` in the context of window, something like this : 
`stopSlider.call(window)` instead of `stopSlider`.

Hope this helps.